# need to invite facebook friends to mysite

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking, invite

I will implement a functionality that let users to invite their facebook friends (explicity choosing or let exclude some of them) to our site  (I dont know what is possible with facebook api but possible cases: 1- sending plain email to friends 2- facebook message, invitation in facebook platform). I am facebook platform newbie  and dont know where to start. Could you recommend which API should I use (facebook connect , facebook graph etc)? I read that facebook api and permission is changing rapidly. What is the state of the art way of doing this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create one facebook app first.

Heres the link for creating facebook app.
https://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php

Then after put the following code in your application.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        //Your app details here
        FB.init({appId: 'your-app-id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

    };


    //Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);

    }());


    </script>


<fb:serverfbml>
    <script type="text/fbml">
        <fb:fbml>
            <fb:request-form
                            action="url-after-inviting"
                            method="POST"
                            invite="true"
                            type="Name of site"
                            content="Text you want to keep along.
                                <fb:req-choice url='link-to-your-website'
                                label='<?php echo htmlspecialchars("Invite Now!",ENT_QUOTES); ?>'/>"
                    >
                <fb:multi-friend-selector
                            showborder="false"
                            actiontext="title-text"
                            exclude_ids="<?php //echo $excludeIds; ?>"
                            rows="3"
                        />
            </fb:request-form>
        </fb:fbml>
    </script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

Comment: Wondering how to do it with on PHP side. Any ideas?

Comment: You can write the same code in your php file as well, as we can put javascript php files. Just put it outside <?php ?> tags

Comment: programmer:do I really have to write facebook app ? Is it possible to use an api without creating facebook app?

Comment: what I meant was to send invitations through PHP SDK, I haven't been able to find a way.

Comment: @GOK Facebook does not allow fbml tabs anymore, so there is no another option but to create facebook application. @ashfame, i have not tested one yet, but the above code works for me.